# idapython: how to get decompiler output corresponding to the indirect call

Tags: ida, idapython

For, e.g. disassembler or IDA view:

[image]

Decompiler or Hex View:

[image]

I can get the decompilation of whole function using something like:

```
decompiled = ida_hexrays.decompile(ea)
```

But, in this way I get the complete decompilation, but not the part which is only highlighted.

For. e.g. I want something like - let's say for the instruction:

```
.text:00000000004011BB                 call    rdx
```

The corresponding decompilation would only be:

```
v4 = ((__int64 (__fastcall *)(_QWORD))a2)(v7) + v3;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably takes more code than it should but here's an approach that could work:

The idea is to use the decompiled function's ctree to narrow down the pseudocode lines you care about. At a glance:

1. decompile the function containing your ea of interest
2. use `citem_t::find_closest_addr()` to find the item most closely matching the instruction at `ea`
3. find the citem's parent statement  (a `cinsn_t`) because the item you found could be anything (for example, a var reference that's an arg to a call that is itself an arg to a call.. etc)
4. once you have your statement, find the corresponding pseudocode lines that match this statement. That also is non-trivial.

   1. each line in the pseudocode (`cfunc_t::get_pseudocode()`) contains 'embedded' references to the citems that contribute to generating that line
   2. the references are indices into the list of citems `cfunc_t::treeitems`
   3. You can find a reasonably simple example in the [Hex-Rays Block Highlighter](https://github.com/vmallet/ida-hex-highlighter) plugin (disclaimer: mine)

Here's some code that will find the parent statement for a given ea (steps 1 through 3 above):

```
def find_parent_cinsn(cfunc, citem):
    if not citem.is_expr():
        return citem
    cinsn = None
    class cvisitor(ida_hexrays.ctree_visitor_t):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(ida_hexrays.CV_FAST | ida_hexrays.CV_PARENTS)

        def visit_expr(self, expr) -> int:
            nonlocal cinsn
            if expr.obj_id == citem.obj_id:
                for parent in reversed(self.parents):
                    if not parent.is_expr():
                        cinsn = parent
                        break
                return 1  # Stop enumeration
            return 0

    cvisitor().apply_to(cfunc.body, None)
    return cinsn


def pseudo_for_ea(ea):
    cfunc = ida_hexrays.decompile(ea)
    citem = cfunc.body.find_closest_addr(ea)
    citem = find_parent_cinsn(cfunc, citem)

    if citem:
        print("Most likely statement for {:X}: {:X}  {}".format(ea, citem.ea, citem.cinsn.opname))

        # Now, cross-ref the pseudocode lines to the citem using the citem
        # references embedded in each line of the cfunc's pseudocode
        #
        # cfunc.citems[] -> 0
        #
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I designed in a way - assuming the first tag contains corresponds to the tag we receive from find_parent_cinsn citem ```if citem:
        for item in cfunc.get_pseudocode():
            if format(citem.index, "X").zfill(16) in item.line.split()[0]:
                decomp = ida_lines.tag_remove(item.line)
                return len(re.findall('\((.*?)\)',decomp)[-1].split(","))```

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented API for this: `find_item_coords(item)`

Thus you can do something like this in IDAPython:

```py
cfunc = ida_hexrays.decompile(ea)
item = cfunc.body.find_closest_addr(ea)
coord = cfunc.find_item_coords(item)
```

The `coord` returned is a `(x, y)` tuple denoting column and row number for the item in the pseudo code.

Hope this can help you.